# PHP $_FILES is empty on a form that was working in the past

Tags: php

I am not sure what the issue is but a client of mine is complaining that an image upload form is not working anymore (has been working for about 6 months). I have searched through endless similar topics here and have gotten no where. Please take a look and let me know if you can spot the issue. Thanks!

Upload form

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="php/upload_sportIcon.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="sport" value="Hockey">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Request payload to php/upload_sportIcon.php

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryFsS3LVjBH0d16a6v
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sport"

Hockey
------WebKitFormBoundaryFsS3LVjBH0d16a6v
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileToUpload"; filename="hockey.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryFsS3LVjBH0d16a6v--
```

upload_sportIcon.php debug functions with output

```
var_dump($_FILES); // array(size=0) empty
sys_get_temp_dir(); // /tmp
php_info();
  // PHP Version: 5.5.32
  // upload_max_filesize: 2M
  // upload_tmp_dir: no value
  // post_max_size: 8M
  // file_uploads: On
```

image: http://demo.jomsoccerbet.com/images/menu_icons/hockey.png (1.94KB)

Tested with Chrome: 56.0.2924.87 and FF: 51.0.1

Comment: did you check for write permissions on upload folder?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: If you don't have any luck, I have a little C++ program that simply dumps the request body, so you can check that PHP isn't munching it. Let me know if you want it, and I'll post it.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte if you look at the examples I provided, I am not even trying to save the file, simply have PHP acknowledge that the user is trying to upload a file

Comment: @alanlittle Yes, at the bottom of the post, I mentioned that I have tried both Chrome and FF. I am interested in the C++ program, how would I run it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see that about the other browsers. I can post the source of the program here, if you have a way to compile it (if not, you could just install an IDE such as Dev C++ and compile it), or if there's some way to contact you off the board, I could send you the program. I'm new to SO, but I haven't seen any kind of PM function.

Comment: Yes, but still, there is a temporary folder where PHP stores uploaded files. If you don't have write permission on this folder (ie: /tmp) you will have the same problem. Just check permissions.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Thanks, I just checked and /tmp is set to 777. I wish it would have been that simple!

Comment: @NickSchild Did you want that C++ POST dump program?

Comment: @alanlittle Yes, please send it to me@nickschild.com Thank you. I can compile it on my linux box and upload it to the server. How do I attach it to Nginx?